# Update bounds Google Maps API swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, bounds

I have a map with markers. When the user tap on a marker, it draw a route. I have created a bound to center the route. If the user taps farther markers there is no problem. But, if the user first tap a farther marker and then a nearest, then the bound used is the first. My code is this:

```
 func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, didTapMarker marker: GMSMarker!) -> Bool {
    reverseGeocodeCoordinate(marker.position)

    markerLocation = marker.position;

    originAddresslong = "\(userLocation.coordinate.longitude)"
    originAddresslat = "\(userLocation.coordinate.latitude)"
    destinationAddresslong = "\(marker.position.longitude)"
    destinationAddresslat = "\(marker.position.latitude)"


    var directionsURLString = baseURLDirections + "origin=" + originAddresslat + "," + originAddresslong + "&destination=" + destinationAddresslat + "," + destinationAddresslong + "&key=AIzaSyB4xO_8B0ZoA8lsAgRjqpqJjgWHbb5X3u0"
    directionsURLString = directionsURLString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    let directionsURL = NSURL(string: directionsURLString)


    Alamofire.request(.GET, directionsURL!, parameters: nil).responseJSON { response in

        switch response.result {

        case .Success(let data):

            var json = JSON(data)
            print(json)

            let errornum = json["error"]


            if (errornum == true){



            }else{
                var routes = json["routes"].array

                if routes != nil{

                    var overViewPolyLine = routes![0]["overview_polyline"]["points"].string
                    let distancia = routes![0]["legs"][0]["distance"]["text"].string
                    print (distancia)
                    print(overViewPolyLine)
                    if overViewPolyLine != nil{

                        if self.routePolyline != nil {
                            self.routePolyline.map = nil
                            self.routePolyline = nil
                        }


                        let path = GMSMutablePath(fromEncodedPath: overViewPolyLine)
                        self.routePolyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
                        self.routePolyline.strokeWidth = 5
                        self.routePolyline.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor()
                        self.routePolyline.map = mapView



                    self.DistanciaLabel.setTitle(distancia,forState: UIControlState.Normal)



                        for index in 1...path.count() {
                            self.bounds = self.bounds.includingCoordinate(path.coordinateAtIndex(index))
                        }

                        mapView.animateWithCameraUpdate(GMSCameraUpdate.fitBounds(self.bounds, withPadding: 125))

                        overViewPolyLine = nil
                        routes = nil
                        json = nil
                        self.path = nil

                    }

                }
            }
        case .Failure(let error):

            print("Hubo un problema con el servidor de direcciones: \(error)")
        }

    }


    return false
}
```

I think that the problem is the line

```
self.bounds = self.bounds.includingCoordinate(path.coordinateAtIndex(index))
```

because, at the Google documentation you can read "Returns a GMSCoordinateBounds representing the current bounds **extended** to include the passed-in coordinate.
If the current bounds is invalid, the result is a valid bounds containing only coordinate." I have tried others functions, but the "including..." didn´t work and i don´t know how to use in swift this format:

```
(id) initWithPath:      (GMSPath *)     path
```

Thanks for all.

Comment: Can you post any error/s you encountered?

Comment: There is no error message. For example, there are two routes, one of 5 km (A) and another of 100 km (B). A is included on the same screen area of B. If i first draw A (smaller zooom) and after B there is no problem and the screen is almost centered on B.
If i first draw B and then draw A the screen doesn´t center on A. It maintains the zoom of B. Bounds didn´t recreate, remember the first bound.